# Unable to migrate database using sqlsrv (could not find driver) in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, sqlsrv

I try to use migrate databse (MS SQL) in laravel 5.4 but I got error:

```
$ php artisan migrate
```

> In Connection.php line 647:
>
> could not find driver (SQL: select * from sysobjects where type =  'U'
>   and name = migrations)

P.S: But for query I can use it's as normal . I have problem only when migration.

Comment: Make sure you have php-mysql module installed and the extension is loaded in both php.ini.

Comment: @thefallen i'm using MS SQL .

Comment: have u solved it? can you share the info, if solved?

Comment: @AliJibran Still can't . i'm still manually  create own table in database.

Comment: The problem is two different php.ini files used by apache and cmd. To solve it, add those extension in php.ini file inside respective PHP version. It's working for me.

Answer (score 2):

## Assuming You are on Windows

#### Install Microsoft PHP Drivers

[Microsoft PHP Driver for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/microsoft-php-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017)

*There are drivers for Linux As well.*

Extract the downloaded file anywhere. We just need the *.dll's.

**FOR WINDOWS10 x 64**

Copy dll's to your PHP\ext Directory.

Ensure **php_pdo_sqlsrv_72_ts_x64.dll & extension=php_sqlsrv_72_ts_x64.dll** are copied.

### Now, Edit your PHP.INI file.

Add the following extensions

**extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_72_ts_x64.dll,
extension=php_sqlsrv_72_ts_x64.dll**

in your PHP.INI file (For windows 10 only, use related dll's on other windows & linux systems)

### Restart Apache2 Server (it's in bin - Alternatively, as service in windows)

./httpd -k restart

### Install MS ODBC Drivers(MUST INSTALL THESE AS WELL)

[ODBC Driver for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017)

-install them.

### Open SQL SERVER CONFIGURATION MANAGER

#### SELECT

PROTOCOLS FOR SQLSERVER

#### SELECT

TCP/IP

#### Protocol

Enabled = Yes

#### IP Address

IPAll 
TCP PORT = 1433

### Restart MS SQL SERVER

Right Click Database Engine (IP Address/MSSQLSERVER)
Restart

### Now You can migrate your models to MS Server

#### LARAVEL .ENV

DB_CONNECTION=sqlsrv

DB_HOST=localhost OR PCNAME\MSSQLSERVERNAME

DB_PORT=1433

DB_DATABASE=yourdatabase

DB_USERNAME=yourusername

DB_PASSWORD=yourpassword

---

**CHECK THE CONNECTION**

```
if(DB::connection()->getDatabaseName())
{
    echo "<h3>connected successfully to database ".DB::connection()->getDatabaseName() . "</h3>";
}
```